# Convert React component to Svelte

Tags: reactjs, autodesk-forge, svelte, autodesk-viewer, react-component

How would someone go about converting a sample React class into Svelte? Specifically, I'm trying to implement this:

https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/extensions/skeleton

in Svelte, however I am not sure how to convert a React class to Svelte. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide any code of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MyAwesomeExtension` of the https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/extensions/skeleton is not a React class. It's just a JavaScript Class following [ECMAScript 2015 (ES6)](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/), the standard of JavaScript. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes.

Forge Viewer's UI is built on top of plain JavaScript DOM API. Unfortunately, we don't have an example built with Svelte framework.